# what install first? sql server 2008 r2 or visual studio 2008 (it is not sp1)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

sooo if i install first visual studio 2008 i get a error, this is because i dont have sp1 for visual studio then i must install it (and it take a lot of time first download and after update it) so, i want to know, if i install first sql server 2008 r2, i am not going to have any problem? after i will install visual studio 2008 (but it is not sp1) i would have any problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install visual studio 2008 first because it's older and will require updates.  When you install SQL you'll probably need updates also but much fewer after you get the updates for VS.  Also you don't want any update to VS to mess up your clean install of SQL